# Azure Application Insights showing incomplete data

Tags: azure-application-insights

I recently had a couple server crash, but you wouldn't be able to tell by looking at Azure Application Insights.
I have a dashboard configured to show Failed Requests, but it only shows that at the time of the crash two requests failed:
[Failed Requests Per Application Insights Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjpOG.png)

However, when I open the App Service Resource, there is a chart that looks more believable (Because I personally made more than a few requests while debugging the issue):
[Failed requests chart on the App Service Resource Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMd2m.png)

How do I get all the Failed Request data to show up in my Application Insights Resource?

Comment: Do you have other traffic other than these failed requests. Can that be sampling?

Answer (score 1):

To get more accurate data for this instance you need to get the server crash data into Application Insights. To get it you need to ensure that you have installed Application Insights Status Monitor on your IIS server. Then you will directly get detailed info intead of only relying on the failed requests.

You can refer to Step #5 in this official link for more details: [Add App Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/)